# polymer - loading core ajax inside an element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

After checking [core-ajax usage](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/customelements.html#nonuielements) in the polymer website I decided to add ajax functionality using core-ajax inside my element/widget.

**test-view.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="test-view" attributes="url">
    <core-ajax id="elemAjax" url="{{url}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
    <template>
        <div id="body"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('test-view', {
        ready: function() {
            var ajax = this.$.elemAjax; // this line
            ajax.addEventListener('core-response', function() {
                console.log(this.response);
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Unfortunately, the "ajax" variable in my script returns "undefined". How can I load ajax inside an element using core-ajax?

Side Question: Is the "id" attribute inside a polymer element only accessible inside the polymer element?

Comment: Re: the side question, essentially yes. Nodes created via a polymer template are created in ShadowDOM (by default), so they are not accessible to queries from outside that ShadowDOM.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Three main problems:

1. The `core-ajax` must go inside the template, so it's part of each instance's DOM (this is why `ajax` was undefined).
2. You need the `auto` attribute on the `core-ajax` (otherwise, you must call the `go()` method on the `core-ajax` to send the request).
3. Your event handler uses `this` but is not bound to the element scope. Suggest you use event delegation instead of `addEventListener`.

See the new example below. The other (less important) tweaks I made:

1. Remove id from `core-ajax`, we don't need to reference it anymore.
2. Remove the `polymer.html` import, `core-ajax` already imports it.
3. Remove the `test-view` parameter to `Polymer()`, it's not necessary when defining an element inside an import.

Modified example:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="test-view" attributes="url">
<template>
    <core-ajax auto url="{{url}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></core-ajax>
    <div id="body"></div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        ajaxResponse: function(event, response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Even better is to avoid events altogether and data-bind directly to the response data. Example:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="test-view" attributes="url">
<template>
    <core-ajax auto url="{{url}}" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
    <div id="body"></div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        responseChanged: function(oldValue) {
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Regarding your "(less important)" tweak #2: Doesn't this make his element more brittle? What if he switches from using core-ajax to some native web component solution in the future? Isn't it best for each element to explicitly declare its dependencies to help with unit testing, for example?

Comment: Possibly, it's arguable. I tend to err on the side of 'the code you don't have to debug, is the code you didn't have to write'.

Comment: I think removing that Polymer import is just asking for trouble down the road. There's no downside to keeping it as `imports` don't re-request the resource if it's already been obtained, and vulcanizing (if you're doing that) eliminates any concern of extra characters. Excluding it, though, leaves you open to inadvertently removing a dependency. /2-cents

Comment: Is  this answer still working in polymer 1.0? I tried it by replacing <polymer-element name=...> by <dom-component id=...> in the custom element definition but can't seem to access the response variable

Comment: For 1.0, `core-ajax` is now `iron-ajax`, `response` was renamed `last-response`, and `handleAs` must be written as `handle-as` (when used as an attribute). Also, in 1.0 `responseChanged` callback must be explicitly prepared via `properties: { response: { observer: 'responseChanged' } }`.